# PHP DateTime Safety

Tags: php, datetime

In my script I want to get today's month and last month, so I do:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$month = date('Ym');
$lastmonth = date('Ym', strtotime('first day of -1 month');
```

How safe is this? Is there a possibility that between the execution of the second and the third line, time has changed (a new month begun) and it therefore returns the same month twice? I know the odds are minimal, but I am dealing with a system that has so many transactions it may be possible.

A safe option I think would be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime();
$month = $dt->format('Ym');
$dt2 = $dt; // to save $dt for later use
$lastmonth = $dt2->modify('first day of -1 month')->format('Ym');
```

But is it really necessary or is there a better way?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question. The second option is indeed the safest bet but also the preferred option. The procedural style is a legacy from when PHP did not have OO-support.

Comment: Get the timestamp once then convert it to any date you want

Comment: `$dt2 = clone $dt;`

Comment: @MateiMihai or `new DateTimeImmutable();`

Comment: Also, I prefer a more readable information `'first day of last month'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @silkfire commented, your second example already is the safest/preferred approach. But, there's a few things/tips to explain.

First of all, as @MateiMihai mentioned, your're copying/saving an object inside another variable. In that case, you should use clone instead of reference copy:

```
$dt = clone $dt;
```

And your code will be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime();
$month = $dt->format('Ym');
$dt2 = clone $dt; // to save $dt for later use
$lastmonth = $dt2->modify('first day of -1 month')->format('Ym');
```

Also, if you have to keep the original object, you should use `DateTimeImmutable` and adapt your code (don't need the `$dt2` variable)

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = new DateTimeImmutable();
$month = $dt->format('Ym');
$lastmonth = $dt->modify('first day of -1 month');//It's a new object with the new date
echo $lastmonth->format('Ym');
```

Also, just as a personal opinion, I prefer a "better readable" approach as:

```
$dt->modify('first day of last month');
```

The result is exactly the same one.

Answer (score -1):

I prefere this way

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // if you didnt it yet...

$t = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01 12:00:00' ) );
// or
$t = strtotime( 'first day of' ); // if you dont need a time // most of the functions are "timesafe"

$date1 = date( 'Ym', $t );
$date2 = date( 'Ym', strtotime( '-1 month', $t ) );
$date3 = date( 'Ym', strtotime( '+6 month', $t ) );
```

This is better to read and works without any difference in any timezone at any time. I set the time to prevent problems of timechanges between the dates.

I dont think, that an object is better or necessary for such a simple result / job. Objects are good, but i dont think thats for every small job the way to go. Nothing is faster than the native functions.
https://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/19/benchmark-strtotime-vs-datetime-vs-gettimestamp-in-php/

Please ignore the comments. He writes only wild comments. Here is nothing unsafe.

Comment: Incorrect. Your `strtotime` can fail. You never check what it produced. You don't know which time zone is being used, so you rely on default time zone that server uses currently. That means you have no idea from which time zone offset this was converted from. It's not easier to read and given what I wrote, your code relies on some default settings that you never even mention. I don't know why you think it's easier to read, because if you ask me - it isn't.

Comment: You mean, that $lastmonth = date('Ym', strtotime('first day of -1 month'); is better to read than $date2 = date( 'Ym', strtotime( '-1 month', $t ) );?

Comment: Basically, you don't like OOP approach so you went with procedural - that's fine, we all have our preferences. But, look what you did - you set the **default** time zone to `UTC`. That affects **all** functions that manipulate date/time. Then, you use `strtotime` which can return `false`. You never check the value. Your code is insecure, **not easier to read** and it doesn't even answer the question. You simply rely on `strtotime` to accept whatever cabbage you throw at it, then you alter the default time zone affecting every single function that deals with date/time. That's not efficient.

Comment: We have no userinput. Why should strtotime return false? And what problem do you have with the timezone. Thats the timezone from this thread

Comment: `strtotime` **can** return false. You can't blindly feed a function whatever and not check what it returns. It's completely irrelevant what the OP wrote, if you're providing code with arguments "this code is better than OOP approach" then **make sure** it's better. Your code is unsafe, worse and harder to read than what the OP wrote in his question. I wrote why your code is worse, it's not even an opinion, it's a fact. Now, you can simply continue using your unsafe code or make it safe. It's totally up to you what kind of code makes you proud.

Comment: Please explane how the function strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01 12:00:00' ) ); or strtotime( 'first day of' ); can return false

Comment: This conversation leads nowhere. You're offended, you won't accept what I wrote so I'll just leave my downvote. It's not my duty to be politically correct to every programmer that gets angry when proven wrong. I think this answer is bad and I explained why. Have a nice day.

Comment: You say thats unsafe and cant explain why. That strtotime can return false isnt new and you say, thats a possibility in my code, which have to be checked... I think no one can answer why

Comment: I explained it to you, but I can't understand it for you.

Comment: I realy try to understand you. Is there a possibility where one of the keywords or keychars would have any other results in other unknown timezones? Or is there a timezone which makes strtotime unable to understand the standard format "2017-05-05 12:00:00"?

Comment: And here is the question of this thread: "How safe is this? Is there a possibility that between the execution of the second and the third line, time has changed (a new month begun) and it therefore returns the same month twice?" My answer is valid and there is nothing unsafe.